# How do I make a floated img have the same height as its parent?

Tags: css, image, html, css-float

I have a footer div which contains some copyright text, and a small logo. I want to set the logo height to be the same height as the div which contains it.

The obvious solution would be `height: 100%`, but this just seems to make the picture appear at its normal height.

Relevant html:

```
<footer>
  <img src="images/circle_logo.png" alt="GriffMUN 2014" title="GriffMUN 2014">
  <p>Details here</p><p>More details here.</p>
</footer>
```

Relevant css:

```
footer {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: small;
  float: center;
}

footer img {
  float:right;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I believe it's supposed to work. http://jsfiddle.net/AEFhV/

Comment: Post some css and html. I wouldn't call `height: 100%` the obvious solution - it doesn't work as one might assume. I would consider setting the image as a background to the div the more obvious solution.

Comment: @Itay That works because the div has been given a specific height.

Comment: @AndyG well he didn't mention the wrapper has a non-fixed height :)

Comment: @Itay, AndyG is right. I want a non-fixed height.

Comment: how about making the logo a background-image instead of using an img element in the markup

Answer (score 1):

add a div in absolute position inside  to accommodate the img

```
<footer>
     <p>Details here</p><p>More details here.</p>
     <div class="new_class"><img src="images/circle_logo.png" alt="GriffMUN 2014" title="GriffMUN 2014"></div>
    </footer>
```

css

```
footer {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: small;
  float: center;
  position:relative;
}

footer img {
  float:right;
  height:100%;
}
.new_class {
    position:absolute;
    right:50px;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    }
```

adjust the div location to your need to see the `<p>` tags

Comment: That works partly; but it ends up with the picture covering my text, which is less helpful.

Comment: And it doesn't work in Chrome. The logo ends up being off the page.

Comment: adjust the 'right:50px;' property of the '.new_class', works fine in my version of chrome.(Version 29.0)

Answer (score 0):

If the footer is a set height, `height: inherit;` should do the trick. If the footer's height is dynamic (ie a percentage rather than a set number) you can use jQuery to match its height to the footer's height, like so:

```
$('footer img').height( $('footer').height() + 'px');
```

This is assuming of course that your img element is contained in a footer element. Hope that helps!

Comment: I am using a footer, but I need to stick to html and css.